# Is it possible to press the key without running the if statement again

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to replace volume media keys with media next-prev keys. The problem is the key volume down  or up gets pressed.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

def on_press(key):
    if key == Key.media_volume_up:
        keyboard.press(Key.media_down)
        keyboard.press(Key.media_next)
    if key == Key.media_volume_down:
        keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
        keyboard.press(Key.media_previous)

def on_release(key):
    pass

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I tried to make it like this but it also triggers the previous if statement so it's looping.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

block = False

def on_press(key):
    global block

    if not block:
        if key == Key.media_volume_up:
            block = True
            keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_down)
            keyboard.press(Key.media_next)
            block = False
        if key == Key.media_volume_down:
            block = True
            keyboard.press(Key.media_volume_up)
            keyboard.press(Key.media_previous)
            block = False

def on_release(key):
    pass

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: you have wrong indentations in second version.

Comment: using `block = False` directly after `press()` can be useless because it will set `block = False` before system run next `on_press` which will check `if not block` - you should rather use it in `if not block: ... else: block = False`

Comment: I don't have media keys so I tested on normal keys and it works for me when I use correct intentations - second `if key` has to be inside `if not block`. But maybe it works in different way for media keys or different system - I use Linux.

Comment: oh it is inside, tabbed wrongly sorry. Also it doesn't work when it's inside

Comment: I used `print(block, key)` before `if not block:` to see if it has expected value `block`

Comment: @furas I don't want to run it like this because it lags my pc so much, I want the working solution

Comment: use `print()` only to debug code - to see if it does what you expected. It helps to find problem and solution. And when you find solution then you can remove `print()`. if you don't want to use `print()` for debuging then learn how to use real debuger.